# How to mock a method to return something else?

Tags: .net, mocking, installation

I have an unit test that needs to mock a method that returns a property of an entity from database. I will put here the some of the code that I tried. If anybody has an idea how to do it and want to help me is welcome. Thanks

This is the interface, the class that implement the interface and the entity model:

```
namespace MoqExample
{
    public interface ISomeService
    {
        Customer GetCustomerById(int customerId);
    }

    public class SomeService : ISomeService
    {
        public Customer GetCustomerById(int customerId)
        {
            // Query database and return Customer;
            return Db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == customerId); 
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMyMethod()
{
    customer = new Customer();
    customer.Id = 1;
    customer. Name= "robert"
    customer.IsActive = true;

    // This works because is mocking a method that return a customer.
    this.Setup<ISomeService, Customer>(c => c.GetCustomerById(customerId)).Returns(task);

    // This doesn't work because is mocking the same method but here I want to return a property 
    this.Setup<ISomeService, bool>(c => c.GetCustomerById(customerId).IsActive).Returns(true);
}
```

Comment: Which mocking framework you use? Also what does `this` refers to? Where does the `Setup` method comes from?

Comment: I use the Moq framework that I installed with NuGet. The Setup method comes from framework and her signature is:

public ISetup<T> Setup<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression) where T : class;
        public ISetup<T, TResult> Setup<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression) where T : class;

Comment: At the moment, your code won't even compile. One reason is this `customer.IsActive = "true";` Also saying "doesn't work" isn't any helpful, instead say what happens? Any compiler error? Or runtime error?

Comment: Now it will compile. Sorry for that error.
This is the message error "System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: c => c.GetCustomerById(customerId).IsActive"